# How to declare a Generics Action in struts2.xml file?

Tags: java, generics, jakarta-ee, struts2, action

My problems is **in a Struts2** action, where

I have a class :

```
public class MyAction<T> extends ActionSupport
```

with a private member like this :

```
private T myData;
```

And I would like to declare this aciton in the **struts.xml** file, 
**how can i manage to do so** ?

Thanks for the answer.

Ps : I've tried without declaration of T, but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you cannot obvioulsy write (in struts-XX.xml)

```
<action name="doSomething" class="xx.xx.MyAction<java.util.Date>">
```

But you can easily code a class (sort of alias) for each parametrization you intend to use.

```
public class MyAction_Date extends MyAction<java.util.Date> {}
```

and then :

```
<action name="doSomething" class="xx.xx.MyAction_Date">
```

Comment: Until struts2 allow to declare a specific type parametrization in it's configuration file, this solution is the best, and I've used it!

Thanks you.
zo

Answer (score 0):

In struts2 the action object is instantiated by the framework for each request.
Then, I don't think  you can use a parametrized class for that. 
(Except if struts allows you to specify a particular class parametrization, say MyAction<Date> , for a particular action mapping - I don't think it allows that)

Comment: That was my point I would like to specify a particular parametrization for a particular mapping, and I don't know if struts2 allow that

Comment: No, but you can easily code a class (sort of alias) for each parametrization you intend to use.
See my other answer